# How to remove marker lines in print composer QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I seem to have stumbled on a really excellent useful feature in qgis print composer which is to add in marker lines to line up content if you click in the x, y coordinates on the side of your layout (the parts with the measurements).

My question is, once i've used them, how to get rid of them.

The marker lines are the red lines on the image below.

[image]

Comment: You mean Guides? Just click them and move them off of themap

Comment: View > Clear Guides does it for you (or toggle View > Show Guides if you just want to hide them)

Comment: @DPSSpatial please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved

Comment: @StevenKay please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1) Manually move the guide off the map by click-and-dragging the guide off the map area

2) View > Clear Guides as suggested by Steven Kay